# How can i Save User ProfileList and check every logon if exist?

Tags: windows, windows-registry, user-profiles

I'm trying to save every sid under:

```
"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\WINDOWS NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\"
```

to some directory and I'm trying to control every logon my backup SID's exist or not under profilelist. if it's not than I must import my saved profiles.

I tried with batch script which I wrote, but my script doing this when an user login and it isn't good way to do this!

I am sharing it for you to understand what I want to do.

(script 1 must run with the user account without admin privileges.)

```
@echo on
IF EXIST D:\Users\ (goto dvar) else goto quit 
:dvar
echo dvar
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
echo %username%>D:\Users\username.txt
for /f "tokens=2 delims= " %%i in ('whoami /user /fo table /nh') do set usersid=%%i
echo %usersid%>>D:\Users\username.txt
echo %userprofile%>>D:\Users\username.txt
IF EXIST D:\Users\%username% (goto GetUserinf) else goto quit 

:GetUserinf
for /f "tokens=1 delims=." %%a in ('echo %userprofile%') do set newpath=%%a
IF %newpath%==%userprofile% (goto quit) else goto run

:run
Dprofile2.bat

:quit
exit
```

---

(script 2 must run with admin privileges.)

```
@echo on

(
set /p user=
set /p usersid=
set /p oldpath=
)<C:\Windows\Temp\username.txt

for /f "tokens=1 delims=." %%a in ('echo %oldpath%') do set newpath=%%a
echo OLD path %oldpath%  ---  NEW path=%newpath%

IF EXIST %newpath% (goto oldexist) else goto quit
:oldexist

:choice
set /P c=For continue "Y", For quit "N" [Y/N]?
if /I "%c%" EQU "Y" goto :reboot
if /I "%c%" EQU "N" goto :quit

:reboot
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\%usersid%" /v "ProfileImagePath" /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "%newpath%" /f
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce" /v "deleteprofile" /t REG_SZ /d "C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /q /c rmdir /s /q %oldpath%"

echo Windows Rebooting.
::shutdown -r -t 0

:quit
exit
```

---

I found a Shell Script but i dont know shell VBS. 
I think with shell scripting this is really easy job.

Can you help me please? I stuck so hard...

```
$objUser = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount(Read-Host -Prompt "Enter Username")
$strSID = $objUser.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier])
#$strSID.Value
Rename-Item -Path "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList\$($strSID.Value)" -NewName "$($strSID.Value).old"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need all of them.
All you need is to do the following;

1- Reg export to some directory ".bat"
2- Reg import from there ".bat"
And time schedule for your 2 batch. "Import every startup" and "Export every logon".
Thats it, cheers.